# 23.04 ubuntu issues when im turning on the system

Tags: 23.04

I have Ubuntu 23.04 version and I have issues:

after sleep mode i can't turn on the system, so i need to force turn it off and then turn it on again

laptop: Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16IAH7H

memory: 32.0 GiB

graphics: NV176 / Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
rocesor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H × 20

any help?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting, please edit your question to include the output of `sudo dmesg`. You're looking for any errors in ACPI or PM that might provide some clues as to why your resume/wake event is failing.